# ¿Como pasar mi calendario a Español?

Tags: javascript, datepicker, fullcalendar

Tengo este código:

```
var calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        //center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1, //  1(Monday) this can be changed to 0(Sunday) for the USA system
    selectable: true,
    defaultView: 'month',

    axisFormat: 'h:mm',
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'ddd',    // Mon
        week: 'ddd d', // Mon 7
        day: 'dddd M/d',  // Monday 9/7
        agendaDay: 'dddd d'
    },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM YYYY', // September 2009
        week: "MMMM YYYY", // September 2009
        day: 'MMMM YYYY'  // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
    },
    allDaySlot: false,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var dt = start.format('DD-MM-YYYY');
       $('#selected_date').html(start.format('DD MMM, YYYY'));
       $('#appointment_list').hide();
       $('#new_list').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../user_operation/appointmentlist?date=' + dt,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 1)
                {
                    $('#new_list').html('<h6>No se encontraron citas en '+start.format('DD MMM, YYYY')+'</h6>');  
                }
                else
                {
                    var t = 1;
                    var list = '<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><th>No</th><th>Patient</th><th>Schedule</th></tr>';
                    $.each(data,function(i,p_name,time){
                        list += "<tr><td>"+t+"</td><td>"+data[i].p_name+"</td><td>"+data[i].time+"</td></tr>";
                        t++;
                    });
                    $('#new_list').html(list); 
                }
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
             
            }
        });
        
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
    drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
        }
    },        
});
});
```

y me aparece así la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con este enlace a ver que tal de la página oficial de FullCalendar: [Cómo utilizar otros idiomas](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/lang)

Answer (score 7):

Tenes que:

- Configurar el [`locale`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/locale) a `es`
- Y cargar el `script` para [español](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale/es.js) o para [todos los idiomas](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale-all.js).

#### Ejemplo `v3`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    locale: 'es'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale/es.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

---

#### Ejemplo `v2`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    locale: 'es'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/dist/lang/es.js"></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: probaré, gracias, pero ya coloqué los cambios:  locale: 'es' y <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale/es.js'></script> pero no me aparece ahora nada de calendario

Comment: al comentariar estas 3 lineas me aparece nuevamente el calendario, pero en inglés siempre. <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/locale/es.js'></script> -->

Comment: <!--calendar css-->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">  
        
        <!-- agregue esta parte para probar calendario -->
        <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.10.2/dist/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

Comment: No, esa parte no es la que quería ver. Eso son los estilos (`CSS`), que dicho sea de paso, tampoco deberías agregar de nuevo el `<link>` al CSS. Entra a ver el `Javascript`, que debe ser algo como, `fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar.min.js` y fijate la versión

Comment: FullCalendar v2.9.0

Comment: No carga ni la página.

Comment: Agregué una imagen al final del post, así es como lo tengo y sí está al final

Comment: Necesito crear una carpeta de languaje->es ?

Comment: No existe carpeta, pero tampoco funciona, se queda cargando la pagina

Comment: Solo tenes que agregar el tag `<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/dist/lang/es.js'></script>` después del `fullcalendar.min.js`  y nada más... si no funciona, no sabría decirte porque.

Comment: siempre me sale error: ahora en el inspector aparece esto: GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/locales-all.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: Eso es porque esa URL no existe ¿de la donde sacaste? La correcta seria `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@2.9.0/dist/lang-all.js`

Answer (score 0):

Al fin solucione el problema del idioma 2021:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

```
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        locales: 'es',
```

(abajo del header hay que poner el locale o locales)

```
      });
      calendar.render();
      
    });
```

Comment: ¿En que se diferencia esta respuesta de la ya realizada por @Marcos?

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso tengo FULLCALENDAR con CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.9/index.global.min.js" integrity="sha256-alsi6DkexWIdeVDEct5s7cnqsWgOqsh2ihuIZbU6H3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Entonces lo que hice fue agregar el **locale** en el código JS

```
locale: 'es'
```

Estuve investigando, leí en la documentación de FullCalendar que puede ser también con

```
lang: 'es'
```

Entre al repertorio de [FullCalendar](https://github.com/Piptonita/crear-calendario-FullCalendar/blob/master/vendor/fullcalendar/locales/es.js) en GitHub y entre las carpetas esta la de

```
vendor/fullcalendar/locales/es.js
```

En este archivo JS esta la configuración para lenguaje en español:

```
FullCalendar.globalLocales.push(function () {
    'use strict';
     var es = {
         code: "es",
         week: {
             dow: 1,
             doy: 4
         },
         buttonText: {
             prev: "Ant",
             next: "Sig",
             today: "Hoy",
             month: "Mes",
             week: "Semana",
             day: "Día",
             list: "Agenda"
         },
         weekText: "Sm",
         allDayText: "Todo el día",
         moreLinkText: "más",
         noEventsText: "No hay eventos para mostrar"
     };
     return es;
 }());
```

En mi caso copie ese código y pegue e un archivo JS el cuál rutee en mi código después del CDN de FULLCALENDAR y con eso tuve suficiente para cambiar el idioma.